# Cannot get content in proper place

Tags: html, css

Im making a small html and css project and ran into a problem.

This is my html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="topText">Met vriendelijke groet,</div>
    <div class="topLine"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left-content">
            <strong>name lastname</strong> <br>
            <p class="name">T</p><p class="address">+31(0)000 000000</p>
            <p class="name">M</p><p class="address">+31(0)0 00000000</p>
            <p class="name">E</p><p class="address">test@test.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-content">
            <strong>name lastname</strong> <br>
            <p class="name">T</p><p class="address">+31(0)000 000000</p>
            <p class="name">M</p><p class="address">+31(0)0 00000000</p>
            <p class="name">E</p><p class="address">test@test.com</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bottomBar"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.topText {
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.topLine {
    height:1pt;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #C80032;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content {
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left-content{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.right-content{

}

.name{
   margin: 0px !important;

}

.address{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.bottomBar {
    float: right;
    width:90%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#7F7B7B;
}
```

Allright to the question, i have 2 divs called left and right content, in that content i have the

attribute.

i would like the output of the html/css to look like this:

**Name Lastname**
T +31(0)000 000000
M +31(0)0 00000000
E test@test.nl

i've tried playing with the margin and that kind of stuf but i cant figure out why it is not properly in place. And its hard to show in the editor here.

Comment: Your issue is you are using a p tag, which comes with a line break.  If you want those on the same line, try either a table structure, or wrapping each in div's with display: inline-block

Answer (score 3):

The tag `<p>` has by default a `display: block;` property (which makes the element go as wide as the container no limiting where your content ends). You should use `<span>` instead (because it has `display: inline;`) or just put the `display: inline` property to your `<p>` tag.

[Future reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 3):

Add "float:left" to ".name" class

```
.name {
  margin: 0px !important;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo and also, don't encourage the use of `!important` this is just a workaround not actually an answer

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `p` tag (paragraph) which as default has margins and considered to be a `block` element.
In order to have two `block` elements you need to use `float` **or** a better solution to change their behavior to `inline-block`.

**Semantics:**

As mentioned `p` tag stands for `paragraph`.
Do you believe it should be wrapped in that tag?
I believe not. Consider using `span` which is an `inline` element.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say, the `<p>` tags are block. The easiest way is to change the name p tags to spans like so:

```
<p class="address"><span class="name">T</span>+31(0)000 000000</p>
<p class="address"><span class="name">M</span>+31(0)000 000000</p>
<p class="address"><span class="name">E</span>test@test.com</p>
```

Changing the `<p>` to `<span>` allows the span to sit inline, so it will sit 'next' to the address.